# Why is R changing my usernames to row numbers? Is there a way to fix my code here?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

```
View(Offense.Passing.Stats) #<--- NOTE: This is a filtered and binded variable through dyplr::bind_rows

                 | Touchdowns | Interceptions |
                 | <int>      | <int>         |
                 | --------   | --------      |
MonsterWyatt...1 | 3          | NA            |
rvmo...2         | 3          | NA            |
MonsterWyatt...3 | NA         | 4             |
rvmo...4         | NA         | 4             | 


library(tidyverse)

Offense.Passing.Stats = Offense.Passing.Stats %>%

 bind_rows() %>%
 gather(statistic, value, "Touchdowns":"Passing.Yards") %>%
 na.omit()

 View(Offense.Passing.Stats)

      |    statistic  | value    |
      |      <chr>    | <int>    |
1     |    Touchdowns |    3     |
2     |    Touchdowns |    3     |
18    | Interceptions |    4     |
19    | Interceptions |    4     |
```

^ **how do I get the "MonsterWyatt", and "rvmo" to come down through the second code? instead of the Row Numbers from the dataframe itself**

I tried to go back and see if I could do a completely different approach on filtering out my variable but it didn't work, so this is the only way to get the variables to pop up like this and have the numbers actually separated out, because if I do it any other way it doesn't actually carry the usernames over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure its just a small fix too

I'm VERY new to R and have no idea really how to fix this small tiny thing in my code.

Comment: You will need to change the row labels and covert them to a column in the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you have to know:

1. tibbles do not accept rownames!
2. data frames do accept BUT the values must be unique so MonsterWyatt-rvmo-MonsterWyatt-rvmo is not possible

Here is one way to come around this problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

Offense.Passing.Stats %>% 
  rownames_to_column("my_rownames") %>% 
  mutate(my_rownames = str_extract(my_rownames, "^\\w+")) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  pivot_longer(-my_rownames, 
               names_to = "Touchdowns", 
               values_to = "Passing.Yeard",
               values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

```
 my_rownames  Touchdowns    Passing.Yeard
  <chr>        <chr>                 <int>
1 MonsterWyatt Touchdowns                3
2 rvmo         Touchdowns                3
3 MonsterWyatt Interceptions             4
4 rvmo         Interceptions             4
```